# Making a UIAlertController standard alert in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, uialertcontroller

I need to create an alert that simply displays a message, so the user can just click "OK" or "Cancel". No action needs to be triggered from that alert. According to the Apple documentation on UIViewControllers (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertController_class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIAlertController/preferredStyle), the following code is used to create a basic alert:

```
  [UIAlertController* alert
  alertControllerWithTitle:@"Insert message title here"
  message:@"Insert message here"
  preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
```

However, when I use this I get an expected identifier error on the asterisk on the first line. Is there any way to resolve this error? Thanks!

**Update**: I simply copied the code wrong. Thanks for your help!

**Update**: I fixed my error but now I am getting a unused variable "alert" warning on the first line. Any ideas?

Comment: Look at the code at the top of the page you linked to. Then look at the code you wrote above. Do you see the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write valid Objective-C code.

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Insert message title here" message:@"Insert message here" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
// and the rest of the code to setup and present the alert
```